# Set userform width from a module by looping through userforms

Tags: vba, userform

Been having a very frustrating problem that I can't seem to find a solution for anywhere - help would be greatly appreciated!

I know how to change the width of a userform from within the userform itself (Me.Width).

The problem is that I am writing a module that will format userforms dynamically. The module is passed a form and it does some manipulations on that form. So far everything works as long as I'm referring to objects on the form.

But I'm now trying to refer to the form itself, and when I try to change the width (of the form, not of a control on the form) I get the error: "Object doesn't support this property or method".

I've tried declaring it as both a UserForm and an Object and all of the other code works in both cases, but resizing the width doesn't. I can see in the immediate window that width isn't available, which is obviously why the code won't execute.

Here's the code that I've tried without succses:

```
Sub frmLoadLayoutTest()

frmLoadLayout frmTest
frmTest.Show

End Sub

Private Sub frmLoadLayout(frmActive As Object) 'Also tried (frmActive as UserForm)

'Setting the width of a control works
frmActive.Controls("labelTest").Width = 100 

'Setting the width of the form itself doesn't work
frmActive.Width = 100

End Sub
```

If anyone can provide an elegant solution, that would be fantastic. Alternatively, is there a way I can refer to the userform by name? (Something like Userform(frm1.name).Width = 100)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the information on [this site](https://exceloffthegrid.com/resize-a-userform-with-vba-or-windows-api/) or [that site](https://www.andypope.info/vba/resizeform.htm) help? For us to supply more insight into your specific problem, please try to reproduce your issue in a small code example and post it here, and detail which line generates the error.

Comment: Agree with @PeterT - it's difficult to imagine exactly what you're doing and where the problem is.  Some code would help a lot here.

Comment: Ahh sorry about that - first time posting, but long time reader so I should have known better! I've adjusted my question with an example code block. Thanks for suggesting those sites - if I understand correctly they relate to dynamic/live sizing. I'm after something much more simple - resize the userform from a module outside of the userform (where I can't refer to 'Me'). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub frmLoadLayoutTest()

    Dim frm As frmTest

    Set frm = New frmTest  '<<< create an instance of the form

    frmLoadLayout frm      '<<< pass in the instance
    frm.Show               '<<< show the instance

End Sub

Private Sub frmLoadLayout(frm As Object)
    With frm
        .Controls("labelTest").Width = 100
        .Width = 300
    End With
End Sub
```

See also why it's good practice to avoid the "default instance" and create your own explicit instance of a form before using it:

https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Comment: Thanks Tim. I didn't know about the issues with using the default instance - had seen a lot of example code that didn't, but hadn't connected the dots around why an explicit instance is better. Unfortunately the solution doesn't work - when I comment out the form width line it does, but I get the same 'Object doesn't support this property or method' error

Comment: Works fine for me, but I tested in Excel so maybe you're using a different VBA host?

Comment: Ahhh, this is very interesting. I'm using Excel as well, so retested in a blank workbook and it worked. So I went back and tried again with all of the other code in the module commented out. Long story short, I traced it down to a function that was being called from within the module, and was passing the form to that module as a variable to do a check. Using your guidance, I created two instances of the form to pass into the main module - one for the function, and the other just for the main module. That's done the trick - thank you!